# Is there a way to automatically change resolution when pluging in a monitor?

Tags: resolution, user, display-adapter

I bought a Cable Matters SuperSpeed USB 3.0/2.0 to HDMI/DVI Adapter  up to 2048x1152/1920x1200 and used it to connect a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2 which allows a  fairly high resolution into an old acer monitor. At first I thought it was broken but then I realized it only worked at a lower resolution. I'm trying to set this up for my mom who isn't much of a technical user. Is there a way to get it to automatically change resolutions when plugged/unplugged?

Comment: Going through a convertor may interfere with the computer recognizing the monitor characteristics.  The fact that it required manual intervention pretty much says that you can't automate the setting.

Answer (score 0):

The monitor may not be able to handle that high a resolution and goes out of synch. Do you hear any high-pitched whistling and clicking as it tries to synch up to the signal? That's usually a sign that the monitor doesn't work at that resolution, and why it can only display a much lower resolution.

You don't say the vintage of the display, but my hunch it probably can't go much more than 1024 x 768 which was high-resolution way back when except on expensive CAD/CAM and graphics systems which used special video cards and monitors capable of the resolutions we use every day now.